# Django csrf_cookie_not_set

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am currently working on a project where the backend is handled by Django and frontend is handled by ReactJS.

The previous developers (they are no longer in the organisation) have developed all the APIs manually. I guess they were not aware of DjangoRestFramework. My job now is to `REST-ify` 50 odd APIs which are currently working.

I am using [DRFs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) generic views, (List, Create, Retrieve...etc).

I am also assigned with the task of implementing [DRFSimpleJWT](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/blob/master/README.rst). The previous developers coded all the functions manually for creating the tokens, what they call it as `custom authentication`.

I have started creating the APIs, my List and Retrieve APIs work fine but whenever the frontend developer does a POST request on a `CreateAPIView`, he's got back a 403 error with the description `csrf cookie not set`.

I also get a 403 error on my runserver log file.

I've tried disabling (commenting) the `permission_classes` and changing it to `AllowAny`.

I then proceeded to disable `authentication_classes` or remove the`session_authentication`

In some cases the data doesn't even go through and `OPTIONS` appears on my server log.

I check the `settings.py` file and see that `csrfmiddleware` is disabled. Enabling it gives csrf error on all requests. I googled and played with cors settings and django settings. Nothing worked.

My view is very simple:

```
MyCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
queryset = ModelName.objects.all
serializer_class =MySerializer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication, SessionAuthentication,]
```

I need help on making the POST request work. Also when I start using SimpleJWT, do I need to specify `authentication_classes` in my Views? Is this related with cors?

The `settings.py`  `REST_FRAMEWORK` is same as DRF documentation.

Thanks. Would really appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your frontend while making POST, PATCH, PUT requests modify your request header to include "X-CSRFToken". The value for this header should be read from your cookie called "csrftoken".

refer these for further information

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#ajax
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#csrf-protection

Comment: How will the front-end developer get the csrf token for the first time?

Comment: when user logs in django will set a csrftoken automatically. For this to be automatic your login mechanism has to use the "login(request, user)" method from "django.contrib.auth".